# Custom highlight not effective unless sourcing vimrc

Tags: vimrc

I customed comment and search highlight in my vimrc, but they are not effective every time I entered vim. I have to source vimrc to make them effective. How can I make them always effective?

```
highlight PMenu ctermfg=225 ctermbg=60 guifg=black guibg=darkgrey
highlight PMenuSel ctermfg=242 ctermbg=225 guifg=darkgrey guibg=black
highlight Comment ctermfg=104 ctermbg=none
highlight Search ctermfg=116 ctermbg=211

syntax enable
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of your `vimrc`?

Answer (score 1):

While it's hard to tell without more information, I suspect you want to use a `ColorScheme` autcommand to have the changes applied whenever a colorscheme is applied:

```
function MyHighlight() abort
  highlight PMenu ctermfg=225 ctermbg=60 guifg=black guibg=darkgrey
  highlight PMenuSel ctermfg=242 ctermbg=225 guifg=darkgrey guibg=black
  highlight Comment ctermfg=104 ctermbg=none
  highlight Search ctermfg=116 ctermbg=211
endfunction

augroup colors | autocmd!
  autocmd ColorScheme * call MyHighlight()
augroup end
```